# Security for two websites talking to each other

Tags: asp.net, rest, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have two websites (one a new MVC app, and the other an older WebForms app). I need them to be able to communicate with each other.

I'm looking at implementing a RESTful Web API on both sites, and then having each site call the other site's Web API.

So far, so good, but what about authentication? I'm looking at [Authentication Filters](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters). They seem like a reasonable approach for the MVC app, but looks like they may be unsupported on WebForms.

My question is, since the only entity that will ever be calling either of these API is the other website, is there a way to simplify this process? For example, could I just have a secret GUID and pass that, and if the other site gets the right GUID, then I assume it's okay?

Note that I will be using HTTPS. Also, we're not a bank. Security only needs to be reasonable and nothing more.

Comment: Look at JWT (Json Web Token) over https between the two sites. should be simple enough to implement that between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup a simple user id/password for the client and pass it in with every request on the Authorization header. Then, creates a custom AuthorizationFilterAttribute to authenticate the credential.

Something like this.

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{   
        public ICustomerAuthenticator CustomerAuthenticator { get; set; }
        
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {   
            var authInfo = $"{actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter}";

            var authenticationResult = CustomerAuthenticator.Authenticate(new []{ authInfo });

            if (!authenticationResult.Authenticated)
            {
                
                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                {   
                    Content = new StringContent("You are not authorized.")
                };
            }
            else
            {
                actionContext.RequestContext.Principal = new GenericPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim("CustomerId", authenticationResult.Customer.Id.ToString()),
                    new Claim("CustomerName", authenticationResult.Customer.Name)
                }));
            }
        }
}
```

Hope this helps.